# Memoir: How to trim set correctly?

Tags: memoir, crop

How do I set the trim correctly? In my case it was wrong on some pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[paperwidth=18cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum}
\hypersetup{pdfpagelayout=TwoPageLeft}

% Trim options
\trimFrame  
\settrimmedsize{24cm}{18cm}{*} 
\settrims{0cm}{0cm}

\title{Memoir with Trim}
\author{R\'egis}
\date{\the\year}
%*******************************************************
\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}
  \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Memoir with Trim}

\section{First section}

\lipsum

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Its is my result, wrong.
[image]

Comment: It seems like you want a page size of 18cm x 24cm, right? Where do you want the trim lines to be?

Comment: Note that the red line, is going over the text. That's not what I want. I want to crop the page normally, with no overlapping text.

Comment: of course it does not work, you cannot mix `memoir` layout settings with `geometry` layout settings. `memoir` use some special settings to handle page setup. These are normalized by `\checkandfixthelayout` but they are not set by the `geometry` package. Solution, use the `memoir` macros to set the layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
%\usepackage[paperheight=24cm,paperwidth=18cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum}
\hypersetup{pdfpagelayout=TwoPageLeft}
\settypeblocksize{16.2cm}{*}{.75}

% Trim options
\trimFrame  
\settrimmedsize{24cm}{*}{.75}
\settrims{0cm}{0cm}


\title{Memoir with Trim}
\author{R\'egis}
\date{\the\year}
%*******************************************************
\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}
  \maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Memoir with Trim}

\section{First section}

\lipsum

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```